# How to get all woocommerce shipping packages in a custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce

I need to let customer edit their pending payment order. By default, woocommerce only allow change the payment method. So, I have created a custom template for this feature.

The problem now I encountered is I can't get the shipping packages in the template. 
Here is the code that I adapted from the wc_cart_totals_shipping_html() :

```
$packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
print_r($packages);
foreach ( $packages as $i => $package ) {
    //blah blah blah        
}
```

The print_r($packages) give me the null array. But on the checkout page, it's working fine. 
Any idea why? Or, get the shipping packages by other method?

Answer (score 5):

Please try this -

```
global $woocommerce;

$customerZipCode =  75098;
$zipResultArr = csd_check_zip_and_state($customerZipCode);
$bh_packages =  $woocommerce->cart->get_shipping_packages();

$bh_packages[0]['destination']['state'] = $zipResultArr['state'];
$bh_packages[0]['destination']['postcode'] = $customerZipCode ;
$bh_packages[0]['destination']['city'] = $zipResultArr['city'];
$bh_packages[0]['destination']['address'] = '';
$bh_packages[0]['destination']['address_2'] = '';

//Calculate costs for passed packages
$bh_shipping_methods = array();

foreach( $bh_packages as $bh_package_key => $bh_package ) {
    $bh_shipping_methods[$bh_package_key] = $woocommerce->shipping->calculate_shipping_for_package($bh_package, $bh_package_key);
}
$shippingArr = $bh_shipping_methods[0]['rates'];
if(!empty($shippingArr)) {
    $response = array();
    foreach ($shippingArr as $value) {
        $shipping['label'] = $value->label;
        $shipping['cost'] = $value->cost;
        $response['shipping'][] = $shipping;
    }
}

// This is your shipping 
print_r($response);
```

Comment: You are awesome, this information was very difficult to find. In my case I was looking for WooCommerce shipping methods when the cart is empty, and this works brilliantly.